# SegFault after calling glDrawArrays

Tags: c++, opengl, sprite

I am attempting to write a sprite batcher. 
Originally, I was uploading the following data to openGL in order to see if I could get anything to the screen:

```
static GLfloat const vertexData[] = {
        //Position                  //Color                 //UV Coords
        0.5f, 0.5f,             1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f,            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f,           1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f,            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f
};
```

These are my Vertex and Fragment Shaders:

```
const char* vert = "#version 330 core\n"
                   "layout (location = 0) in vec2 vPos;\n"
                   "layout (location = 1) in vec4 vColor;\n"
                   "layout (location = 2) in vec2 vTexPos;\n"
                   "\n"
                   "out vec4 fColor;\n"
                   "out vec2 fTexPos;\n"
                   "\n"
                   "void main() {\n"
                   "    gl_Position = vec4(vPos.xy, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
                   "    fColor = vColor;\n"
                   "    fTexPos = vec2(vTexPos.s, 1.0 - vTexPos.t);\n"
                   "}";




const char* frag = "#version 330 core\n"
                   "in vec4 fColor;\n"
                   "in vec2 fTexPos;\n"
                   "out vec4 finalColor;\n"
                   "\n"
                   "uniform sampler2D textureUniform;\n"
                   "\n"
                   "void main() {\n"
                   "  vec4 textureColor = texture(textureUniform, fTexPos);"
                   "  finalColor = fColor * textureColor;\n"
                   "}";
```

I set up the VAO and VBO like so:

```
auto vaoID_ = 0;
auto vboID_ = 0;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID_);
glGenBuffers(1, &vboID_);

glBindVertexArray(vaoID_);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID_);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8, (void*)0); // Screen Position
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8, (void*)(2 *sizeof(GL_FLOAT)); //Color
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8, (void*)(6 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)); //UV
```

And finally, on each loop, I would orphan the buffer and then sub the data in.

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

This worked fine!
So, I attempted to begin to write a basic sprite batch.
I grouped my vertex data into a POD struct:

```
   struct VertexData {
        struct {
            GLfloat screenx;
            GLfloat screeny;
        } position;

        struct {
            GLfloat r;
            GLfloat g;
            GLfloat b;
            GLfloat a;
        } color;

        struct {
            GLfloat texu;
            GLfloat texv;
        } uv;
    }
```

And used a vector to batch everything together:
`std::vector<VertexData> spritebatch_`

I changed the calls to `glVertexAttribPointer` to match this struct (although I think this change was unneeded?)

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (void*)offsetof(VertexData, position)); // Screen Position
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (void*)offsetof(VertexData, color)); //Color
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (void*)offsetof(VertexData, uv)); //UV
```

To test it, on every loop I would feed it the same data that was in the static `GLfloat` array:

```
spritebatch_.push_back({0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f});
spritebatch_.push_back({-0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f});
spritebatch_.push_back({0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f});
spritebatch_.push_back({-0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f});
spritebatch_.push_back({-0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f});
spritebatch_.push_back({0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f});
```

And then attempt to orphan the buffer and sub the data in:

```
glBufferData(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, spritebatch_.size() * sizeof(VertexData), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, 0, spritebatch_.size() * sizeof(VertexData), spritebatch_.data());
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, spritebatch_.size());
```

Finally, I would reset the spritebatch_: `spritebatch_.clear();`

However, this segfaults. Am I doing something incorrect when I go to orphan the buffer and sub the data in? The data formats still match (`VertexData` POD members are all `GLfloat`s still), the size of `spritebatch_` is still 6 (6 vertices to make a square), and the location of that data is still the same within each vertex.

Comment: GL_VERTEX_ARRAY should be GL_ARRAY_BUFFER? Make sure you have the buffer bound when you call glVertexAttribPointer.

Comment: The 5th parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is the "stride", the **byte offset** between consecutive generic vertex attributes. So the change is important, because `sizeof(VertexData)` is not 8, but it is `8*sizeof(GL_FLOAT)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5th parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is the "stride", the **byte offset** between consecutive generic vertex attributes.

So the change from

> ```
>  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8, (void*)0); // Screen Position
>  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8, (void*)(2 *sizeof(GL_FLOAT)); //Color
>  glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8, (void*)(6 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)); //UV
> ```

to

> ```
> glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (void*)offsetof(VertexData, position)); // Screen Position
> glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (void*)offsetof(VertexData, color)); //Color
> glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (void*)offsetof(VertexData, uv)); //UV
> ```

is important, because `sizeof(VertexData)` is not 8, but it is `8*sizeof(GL_FLOAT)` .

---

The first parameter of [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) respectively [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) has to be the enumerator constant for the target, which is one of  `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, ... .
`GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` identifies the vertex array for the fixed function client-side capability - See [`glEnableClientState`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es1.1/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml).

Change:

<s>`glBufferData(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, ...);`</s>
`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...);`

<s>`glBufferSubData(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, ...);`</s>
`glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...);`

Note, if you would check for OpenGL errors ([`glGetError`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml) or [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output)), you would get a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error.
The data store for the array buffer is not created, this causes the segment fault.